# How can I set default paths for INCLUDE blocks under each heading in orgmode?

Tags: org-mode

I am writing a document where I have a collection of code for different topics. My document structure is as follows.

```
* Heading1

Some text
#+include: "Heading1/file11.py" src python

Test illustrating something else
#+include: "Heading1/file64.py" src python


* Heading2

Some text
#+include: "Heading2/file84.py" src python

Test illustrating something else
#+include: "Heading2/file96.py" src python
```

My directory structure is as below.

```
.
├── Heading1
│   ├── file11.py
│   └── file64.py
└── Heading2
    ├── file84.py
    └── file96.py
```

Is there a way I can do something like the following where I declare each base folder under each heading so that I don't have to repeatedly write the heading when I include the source file?

```
* Heading1
#+declare base foldername as Heading1

Some text
#+include: "file11.py" src python
```

Comment: I don't think so.

Comment: @NickD alright, so is there a better way for my process that I can improve? I somehow find that I might be inefficient... Not sure..

Comment: IMO there is very little efficiency to be gained by having the pathname filled in automatically, but it all depends on the numbers. If you have a lot of `include`s and the pathname is long and complicated, then type it once, save it in a buffer and yank it every time you need to  (or equivalently, copy it to the clipboard and paste it)- you can take care of minor differences, like the appended number after "Heading" in your example, by typing it by hand. If it gets tiring and repetitive, *then* you automate more. Note that there are stages of automation too: it's not all or nothing.

Comment: You might also look into [keyboard macros](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Keyboard-Macros.html#Keyboard-Macros) : it allows you to record  a series of keys and save them in a macro. The macro can then be replayed.